# Codeigniter loading different controllers for mobile

Tags: php, codeigniter, mobile

I am looking for solution how to load different controllers not changing website uri for mobile devices. For example I'm going to www.site.com via PC and I should see webpage (works by default, everything is ok). But now I'm going www.site.com via mobile and I want to see mobile version of this website not changing url's. So when I will go to www.site.com/article-123 via mobile, I want to see mobile version of page. I'm looking for solution, but I haven't found anything. I tried to load user_agent library to my routes file, but nothing happened (wanted to change call to controllers for mobile devices). Is there any solution?

Comment: Try [tag:responsive-design] for your website.

Comment: Responsive design is not a solution becouse in mobile version there is less info parsing to views

Answer (score 1):

**Quote OP**:

> "I tried to load user_agent library to my routes file, but nothing happened."

I don't know how you'd add a library to the `routes` since you never showed us, but see [the documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/user_agent.html) for proper usage of the `user_agent` library.  Then use the [`url`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) helper to `redirect` to a different Controller function.

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
$this->load->helper('url');

if ($this->agent->is_mobile())
{
    redirect('/mobile/home/', 'refresh'); // go to 'mobile' controller, 'home()' function
}
else
{
    redirect('/desktop/index/', 'refresh'); // go to 'desktop' controller, 'index()' function
}
```

Comment: thanks, but isn't `refresh` mean that the page will be refreshed? becouse this is what happening to me. The page is refreshing without stopping

Comment: @user3744738, so try `'location'` instead of `'refresh'`; but no, `refresh` is not supposed to refresh the page without stopping... and `redirect` is simply supposed to redirect you to a new page.  It sounds like you have something screwy in your `routes` file.